# Raspberry Pi 3 model b+ does not give any output

Tags: pi-3b+

For some reason my Raspberry Pi 3 model b+ does not want to boot and does not give any output signal. I tried several SD cards with fresh OS on them.  What I noticed is that the green LED shows the same signal: long-short-short-long and then nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://support.pishop.ca/article/33-raspberry-pi-act-led-error-patterns

Comment: 3B+ should be bootable from USB out of the box. Try that

Comment: ^^ if it boots from USB, you may have a faulty SD card slot (physical, electrical, who knows) - the LED flash pattern doesn't match any pattern documented for a 3B+, so that's not helping. has this Pi ever booted? is it brand new?

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

That LED sequence indicate that there is something wrong with you boot from the SD card.

You state that you have tried several SD cards, but how do you create your SD cards? It looks like you are creating the SD cards from a faulty image or with the wrong imaging tool.